# Django and Django rest framework serializer multiple relation tables

Tags: django, function

There are three models:

```
class QLabel(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    label = models.ForeignKey(QLabel, related_name='qdetail', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Path(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(QLabel, related_name='ask', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    next_q = models.ForeignKey(QLabel, related_name='next', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And the serializers.py like this:

```
class PathSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    q = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='question', read_only=True)
    nq = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='next_q', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Path
        fields = ('q', 'nq')
```

The results as follow:

```
    {
        "q": "Q1",
        "nq": "Q2",
    },
```

Instead of "Q1", how to obtain Q1 related question from Question models. For example:

QLabel

```
id label
--------
1   Q1
2   Q2
```

Question

```
id question         label
-------------------------
1  How old are you.   Q1
2  What's your name.  Q2
```

What the results I want:

```
   {
    "q": "How old are you.",
    "nq": "What's your name."
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have tried many methods which I can google. But failed. I think it is not a complex problem which really confused me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see your db design it is not suitable for your answer and according to me `label` field in `Question` must one to one field with `QLabel` not one to many, like this:-

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    label = models.OneToOneField(QLabel, related_name='qdetail', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

For this you can add serializer like this :-

```
class PathSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    q = serializers.CharField(source='question.qdetail.question', read_only=True)
    nq = serializers.CharField(source='next_q.qdetail.question', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Path
        fields = ('q', 'nq')
```

But if you trying with same db design then for readonly purpose you can do like this :-

```
class PathSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    q = serializers.SerializerMethodField(allow_null=True)
    nq = serializers.SerializerMethodField(allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Path
        fields = ('q', 'nq')

    def get_q(self, path_instance):
        return path_instance.question.qdetail.first()

    def get_nq(self, path_instance):
        return path_instance.next_q.qdetail.first()
```

You can refer for SerializerMethodField from https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: It gives me lots of ideas.  Although SerializerMethodField works, the models structure are not good enough.